# inotifywait not detected in /sys/class/gpio/gpioXX/ (raspberry pi)

Tags: raspberry-pi, inotify, gpio, inotifywait

I have connected 2 raspberry pi using GPIO : 
The first one is the master, and use GPIO2 (and GND...)
The second one is a slave, and use GPIO0 and GPIO1
All are switch on a relay card

I put GPIO1 and GPIO0 on direction "**IN**" and GPI02 on direction "**out**" :
    *echo in > /sys/class/gpio/gpioXX/direction*

On my master, (GPIO2, direction = **OUT**), when i put the pin GPIO2 to 1, the 2 pins on my slave turn to 1 too. So, no probleme here

I add a shell script, using inotifywait on one folder (for example  **/sys/class/gpio/gpio18/**  (18 for GPIO1)).

When I'm on my SLAVE, and i try to modify the value of /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/ with an echo 1 > .../value , inotifywait catch a modification, but the value didn't change ( *-bash: echo: write error: Operation not permitted* , it's normal because direction is on "IN" ).

When I'm on my MASTER, and i modify the value of gpio27 (corresponding to GPI02), both value file (GPIO0, GPIO1 and GPIO2) change, but my inotifywait didn't catch the modification on gpio/gpio18/value (the containt of the file change from 0 to 1 or inversely)

Answer (score -1):

I can't say for sure what is wrong. But I would try running a simple script like this and see what happens:

```
while inotifywait -e modify /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/; do echo "Hello"; done
```